# How to prevent $setViewValue from firing up $watch

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've made a directive that wrapps a jQuery Plugin:

```
angular.module('ngJQueryPlugin', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.input = {'hexa': 0};
  })
  .directive('jQueryPlugin', function ($compile, $parse) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes, ngModel) {
          if (ngModel === null) return;
          $scope.$watch($attributes.ngModel, function (hexaFromModel) {
            $element.data('jQueryPlugin').updateJQueryPluginUI(hexaFromModel);
          }, true);
          $element.jQueryPluginConstructor({}, function (hexaFromjQueryPlugin) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
              ngModel.$setViewValue({ hexa: hexaFromjQueryPlugin});
              ngModel.$render();
            });
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

Directive instantiation:

```
<jquery-plugin ng-model="input" />
<input type="text" ng-model="input.hexa"/>
```

The scope watch in the directive tracks each model update and notifies the jQueryPlugin.

The second parameter in the jQueryPlugin constructor is a callback function that is called each time the jQueryPlugin UI updates the hexadecimal color. It then sets the new value on the scope.

My problem is that the $setViewValue causes the $watch to be called. $watch updates back the jQueryPlugin, which is useless since we've initially got notified from the jQueryPlugin callback.

A solution I've thought of is to use flags on the scope to know wether the update has initially started in the jQueryPlugin or in the scope. That would prevent recursive calls.

Is there any another way to do that ? For example by preventing $setViewValue to firing up $watch even if the model has been updated ?

**UPDATE:**
I've just created a plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/avumn9MJwdjmxHNtrmSF?p=preview
If I enter text in the first input (from Angular), the jQuery plugin is notified: Normal behavior.
If I enter text in the second input from jQuery component, it should not be notified back.

Comment: It seems you do not want a two-way binding. Why do you use the `ng-model` then?

Comment: I do want a two-way binding. This is what I am aiming to have. The issue is that have this: jQueryPlugin update => Callback => $setViewValue => $watch. I do not what the $watch to be called in that case (the $setViewValue'd have already performed the binding). But I need it to be called in this scenario: Scope (model) update => watch => jQueryPlugin update.

Comment: Could you just set `$viewValue` directly then, but that will bypass `$formatters` as well.

Comment: ngModel.$viewValue = {hexa: hexaFromjQueryPlugin}; doesn't modify the scope. How would you set it directly ?

Comment: I see what you mean now, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
      $scope.$watch($attributes.ngModel, function (hexaFromModel, oldValue) {
        if (hexaFromModel === oldValue) {
          return;
        }

        $element.data('jQueryPlugin').updateJQueryPluginUI(hexaFromModel);
      });
```

Note that this does not stop the watch from being called, but stops the watch logic from being run if there is no change.

Comment: This doesn't work if we compare for object equality using angular.equals instead of comparing for reference equality via  $scope.$watch($attributes.ngModel, function (hexaFromModel) { if (hexaFromModel === oldValue) // always false      
          }, true);

Comment: Please see the update on the initial question. I've created a plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

One way to detect that a change come from `ngModel.$setViewValue()` is to compare against `ngModel.$modelValue`. You could do it like this:

```
$scope.$watch($attributes.ngModel, function (hexaFromModel) {
  if (angular.equals(hexaFromModel, ngModel.$modelValue)) {
    return;
  }

  $element.data('jQueryPlugin').updateJQueryPluginUI(hexaFromModel);
}, true);
```

Or probably you could also use the `$formatters` instead of watching `$attributes.ngModel` like this:

```
ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
  $element.data('jQueryPlugin').updateJQueryPluginUI(value);
});
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** It turned out the `hexaFromModel` is actually an object, not a simple string, and that has rendered the above solution useless.

In this case, I can't think of any solution better than setting a flag to bypass the watch listener if the update come from the plugin. Like this:

```
var updatingByPlugin = false;

$scope.$watch($attributes.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (updatingByPlugin) {
    return;
  }

  jQueryPlugin.update(newValue);
}, true);

jQueryPlugin = new jQueryPluginConstructor($element, {}, function(hexFromjQueryPlugin) {
  console.log('notified');

  updatingByPlugin = true;

  $scope.$apply(function () {
    ngModel.$setViewValue({
      hex: hexFromjQueryPlugin
    });
  });

  updatingByPlugin = false;
});
```

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/HH1lw7Pk31tsyri9h0w7?p=preview

Comment: If I enter text in the first input (from Angular), the jQuery plugin is notified: Normal behavior. If I enter text in the second input from jQuery component, it should not be notified back.

Comment: I see, the `hexaFromModel` is actually an object. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot runTarm for your help and the plunker. Actually, I'd already thought of the flag solution (as described in the initial question). I was hoping that angularJs were offering some internal mechanism that would prevent $setViewValue from callbacking $watch. :(

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to write a $render function, and not to call it:

```
angular.module('ngJQueryPlugin', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.input = {'hexa': 0};
  })
  .directive('jQueryPlugin', function ($compile, $parse) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes, ngModel) {
          if (ngModel === null) return;
          ngModel.$render = function () {
                 if(ngModel.$viewValue)
                     $element.data('jQueryPlugin').updateJQueryPluginUI(ngModel.$viewValue);
          }
          $element.jQueryPluginConstructor({}, function (hexaFromjQueryPlugin) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
              ngModel.$setViewValue({ hexa: hexaFromjQueryPlugin});
            });
          });
        }
      };
    });
```